# Bundled products within a configurable product?

Tags: configurable-product, bundled-product, stock

My client has an online store selling a number of simple products:

Light Wax
Medium Wax
Strong Wax
Extra Strong Wax

They also want to sell "box sets" combining pairs of products, specifically:

Light Wax + Medium Wax
Medium Wax + Strong Wax
Strong Wax + Extra Strong Wax

Furthermore, they want a parent product called "Box Sets" with the options above selected via dropdown, similar to this example image:

[image: Dropdown similar to custom options]

My client prepares these box sets from the individual (simple) products as they are ordered, so stock management is important - when a customer makes their selection and completes the order, the stock levels of the associated simple products should also decrease appropriately.

So far, I can create a bundled product for each combination above, but it doesn't seem possible to assign them to a configurable product - this would allow the customer to select which bundle they want via the dropdown on the parent product page.

Is there a way to achieve this out-of-the-box or can anyone recommend a workaround or how to achieve this via an extension? (I looked at the [Brim Grouped Options extension](http://ecommerce.brimllc.com/grouped-options.html) but I'm not convinced that it's the correct solution)

Many thanks!